# PDF Snapshot Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm not sure if this is possible. I've search one google etc but not joy (maybe because it's not possible)

I have a simple 1 page PDF with a few editable text boxes on.

I'm trying to create some code that allows a button to be pressed and it will take a snapshot of the whole page, which then can be pasted in a email for example.

I know i can use PrtScr but i'd rather not have the toolbars etc for windows. Just looking for the A4 page.

Comment: have you tried [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did look at that, but i need it so it's all in the pdf. The computer used won't have access to any url's or external services. Apart from a internal mail client.

Comment: jspdf doesn't utilize any external services. it uses a webworker, which is local. if you can use javascript you can use jspdf.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, But i'm not able to download any files to the computer. I'm assuming i have to have these files on the PC?

Comment: you can't download *any* files? how are the users downloading your code then?

Comment: The PDF will be sent to them as a email attachment. Which they can then press the button to take a snapshot of the page which then can pasted into a email body. 

The users can't save anything to the PC. Sounds strange but restrictions set by IT, which can't be lifted.

Comment: you can't run any kind of javascript from an email. if IT is telling you to do something like this you should hire a new IT team, otherwise have them figure this out.

Comment: I know you can't.
Basically i'm looking for a few users to fill in a form to send me details back.
IT don't allow anything to be attached so they can't save the PDF andd return it. However they can paste images into the email.
So i was hoping once they fill in the form and took a snapshot of the whole page they can paste that into the email and least i can see there replies to each section of the form.

Our IT team are very controlling and like to limit us.

Comment: you're not telling the whole story. instead of me continuing to ask questions just post the whole story. i'm volunteering to help because i like to help, not because i like to play 20 questions.

Comment: If you're looking for users to fill out a form, can you not just send the form data back as text or json? Why do you need a visual screen capture?